# Gradle - multi project compiles but shared project classes not found

Tags: java, spring, build, gradle

We are trying to setup a multi project build.

We have 2 projects:

1) PlayerManager 
2) Shared

our project compiles and all the tests succeed when we run the gradle.test task

Problem is when we try to run the project on the tomcat from whithin eclipse we get class not found error for all the files in the Shared project.

Here is our gradle.build files:

PlayerManager (root)

```
=======================

apply plugin: 'war' 
apply plugin: 'jetty' 
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp' 
apply plugin: 'eclipse' 
apply from: 'dependencies.gradle' 
apply from: 'xmlHandler.gradle' 
apply plugin: 'base'

dependsOn(":NGShared:NGShared")

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { 
gradleVersion = '1.9' 
}

repositories { 
mavenCentral() 
}

dependencies { 
providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5' 
compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.2.RELEASE' 
runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2' 
}

/* Change context path (base url). otherwise defaults to name of project */ 
jettyRunWar.contextPath = ''

task cleanAndBuild(dependsOn: ['clean', 'assemble'])

assemble.mustRunAfter clean

tasks.withType(Test) { 
testLogging { 
events 'passed' 
} 
}

task testSanity(type: Test, dependsOn: testClasses) { 
exclude '*/TimeBaseTest*' 
}
```

Shared(sub project)

```
=======================

apply plugin: 'java' 
apply plugin: 'eclipse' 
apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { 
gradleVersion = '1.9' 
}
```

settings.gradle

```
include ":NGShared:NGShared"

======================================================

Our path for the project is:

/NGPlayerManager/ 
/NGPlayerManager/NGShared/NGShared
```

Any ideas why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run 'gradle eclipseClean' and then 'gradle eclipse' in order for gradle to regenerate all internal eclipse config files?  If you don't do this, Eclipse will not automatically regenerate its configuration and will not include your child projects into the .ear or .war package

Comment: I think i got it!  Change that `dependsOn(":NGShared:NGShared")` for

`dependencies { /* rest of dependencies...*/
compile project(':NGShared:NGShared')
}`